# How to append the label text in the same line using jQuery appendTo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append the text for the label when clicking Add Label button, in one line like below,

value1, value2, value3 and etc....

But I am not able to achieve what I want, what is going wrong here? here is the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/KendoDev/7ot577qp/

```
<div style="display:inline">
    <button id="addButton" > Add Label </button>

</div>
<div id="holder">




  $(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0 ;
    var labelID = '';
    $("#addButton").click(function(){
     i = i+1; 
        labelID= 'label'+i+ ',';
        $('<div />', {

        })
            .addClass("label")
            .appendTo("#holder");
        $('<label />', {
            for: 'holder'       
        })
           .attr('id', labelID)
           .text("Value" + i)
           .appendTo("#holder")
        .click(function (e) {
                var name = $('#'+labelID).text();
            alert("event fired: text is: "+ e.currentTarget.textContent + " \n label id is:   " + e.currentTarget.id);
        });    
        $('<div> , </div>')
            .appendTo("#holder");

    });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use block level elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/KendoDev/7ot577qp/9/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var i = 0 ;
var labelID = '';
$("#addButton").click(function(){
 i = i+1; 
    labelID= 'label'+i+ ',';
    $('<span>')
        .addClass("label")
        .appendTo("#holder");
    $('<label>', {
        for: 'holder'       
    })
       .attr('id', labelID)
       .text("Value" + i)
       .appendTo("#holder")
    .click(function (e) {
            var name = $('#'+labelID).text();
        alert("event fired: text is: "+ e.currentTarget.textContent + " \n label id is:   " + e.currentTarget.id);
    });    
    $('<span> , </span>')
        .appendTo("#holder");

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`div` is like a **block** so it takes complete space for it and your next element starts after the div, by default `div` **display** property is **block**, change it to **inline** so that it does not take all space and allows to have elements in front of it to display all in single line:

```
$('<div> , </div>').css("display","inline")
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/7ot577qp/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are trying to acheive

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0 ;
    var labelID = '';
    $("#addButton").click(function(){
        i = i+1; 
        $('<div><label for="holder" id="label'+i+'">Value'+i+'</label>,</div>').appendTo("#holder");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var i = 1;

    $("#addButton").click(function(){
        $('#holder').append("<label for='holder' id=label"+i+">Value"+i+", </label>");
        i++;
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ot577qp/4/